# What type of fuse should I use for this basic electronics design?

Tags: arduino, current-measurement, fuses

I'm creating a simple Arduino project that utilizes a solenoid and a rotary encoder. I'm powering the entire device with a 12V 5A switching power supply. I want to add a fuse to the design but can't figure out what capacity to use. My options (as far as I can find) are 200mA, 500mA, or 5A. I predict the device will draw a max of about 760mA so the 5A fuse seems sensible but also pretty high.

From what I've found, the devices will pull the following current:

- Solenoid: ~580mA (based on 7W/12VDC)
- Rotary Encoder: ~16mA @5V
- 5V Regulator on Trinket: ~150mA max

---

- First, am I calculating the current draw correctly?
- Second, is the schematic configuration sensible?
- Third, what size fuse should I be considering?

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Schematic for device]

Comment: What are you trying to protect? There may be better ways of achieving it. With a solenoid that likely draws a large amount of current for a very short time your options to protect other components may vary.

Comment: I guess my thinking was to try to protect the device (everything the power plug "powers") from surges of power originating from the power supply. With the high level of currents running through the solenoid, I imagine that the transistor will get pretty hot and might benefit from a fuse on the collector. What do you think needs the most protection?

Comment: Fuses aren't to protect against "Surges".  They protect against overcurrent events.  For a solenoid, you will need a time delay fuse most likely, and there are many more fuse ratings then those you listed.  In that circuit, if you fused anything, it would be to attempt to protect the switching transistor, but even if an event happened and the fuse cleared, there is no guarantee that the transistor will survive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm new to the practical applications of circuit building. So would you recommend removing the fuse I currently have in the design and move it between the solenoid and the transistor?

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to use a normal fuse, go with a normal 250v 1A fuse. You could also use a resettable fuse aka PPTP but it will add more impedance to your circuit in some circumstances.